# empty vector allows push back first element of itself

Tags: c++

One friend of mine showed very simple example:

```
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    vector<int> v;
    v.push_back( v[0] );

    return 0;
}
```

It compiles, without any warnings. Problems with templates should be detected at compile time. What is your explanation of this strange behavior?

Comment: Template problems *are* detected at compile time. But there is no template problem here. What’s to detect?

Comment: Besides, how does the compiler know that the vectors will be initialized empty, what a vector is and what v[0] should return?

Comment: This is not even _necessarily_ an error, so the compiler probably should not complain, even if it could easily detect such a case. For example, with `std::map`, it is entirely legitimate to call `operator[]` with an index that does not exist, this will return a reference to a newly default-constructed element. Insofar, the compiler should not make assumptions about wrong use that it can't positively know about.

Comment: If you are worried about buffer overruns you should be using `at()`. Try `v.push_back(v.at(0));` See if that works. The `v[0]` variant is supposed to be used in code where you **know** that 0 is available (ie checks have already been done and you don't want to check again) If you have not done the validation of the index you are supposed to use `at(0)` or validate the index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this seems like a runtime issue not a compile time issue to me. how is the compiler supposed to know how vector runs?

Answer (score 2):

Problems with template instantiation should be detected at compile
time, but once instantiated, the results of the instantiate behave
exactly as any other class or function.  Detecting errors like the one
you show is impossible in general, and they result in undefined behavior
at run-time.

Answer (score 2):

This situation triggers undefined behavior - the compiler is not required to recognize it, although it could try to. So anything can happen - the compiler could warn you or this code could cause a runtime problem or you would not observe anything negative at all.

Comment: +1 for “it could try to”. The other answers all presuppose that the compiler cannot detect this error *in principle*. That’s not obvious (and not true).

Comment: @Konrad: The compiler `could check` a lot of things. But how do you priorities the order you write the tests for UB and then go about writing them. I think test for `const expression` of `operator[]` is `in range` for a `local vector` using `default constructor` that `has not previously modified` check is probably at the bottom of some list and in general will not be that useful.

Comment: @Martin: this is all very well – and probably the reason why it’s not done. But it’s not the same as saying that it cannot be done in principle. For example, forbidding reading from an empty vector is conceptually very simple in a side-effect free system (i.e. with an immutable vector).

Comment: @Konrad: I am saying that the test is so specialized (like most of these tests that are obvious to humans) that it is useless to add (unless you add all of them). Then the number of these specialized tests is so outrageously large that is not doable (in any meaningful way).

Answer (score 0):

I would say that this is not a compile-time problem.  At compile-time the compiler doesn't know, or care that the vector is empty.

At runtime I would expect an exception to occur when you try to access the first element of the vector.

Comment: An exception will not occur because `operator[]` does not do any bounds checking. A signal (not an exception) may occur because `v[0]` might well be dereferencing a null pointer. The program might well push a chunk of garbage onto the vector. Anything at all can happen here because this is undefined behavior.

Comment: Indeed, when I said "exception" I meant that you would likely get a memory access error - of course that's not guaranteed as it depends on how the memory is allocated. But point taken :)

Answer (score 0):

Even at runtime, the behaviour of this code is undefined.  If you want deterministic behaviour (in the form of an exception to flag the error) on vector bound misuse, you need to use [vector::at()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6kkh778.aspx) instead of `vector::operator[]`.